# Spring - @Transactional - when will it flush data?

Tags: spring, hibernate, session, annotations, spring-orm

I am using **Spring 4.3.4.RELEASE** with **Hibernate 5.1.15**
As part of hibernate migration from 3 to 5, I am facing some issues related to transactional annotation.

Consider the case where one method contains 2 different methods with/without transaction annotation.
In hibernate 3 it used to work properly. But after upgrade to hibernate 5 method setEMSStatus is failing as subscribedEms is null.

createAndSaveSubscribedEms is not flushing the data to the database.
Because of which setEMSStatus does not get the data from database and hence get null.

Explicity adding flush would work. But there might be 100's of places with similar case. so adding explicit flush doesn't look like a viable solution.

```
//Class1
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public void validateAndSave(List<EmsDto> gridList) {
    //Removing unnecessary code
    emsEntityManager.createAndSaveSubscribedEms(EmsDto.getMessageName(), EmsDto.getDescription(), SubscribeEmsStatus.UNKNOWN.toString());
    //Removing unnecessary code
    emsEntityManager.setEMSStatus(entry.getKey(), SubscribeEmsStatus.VALID.toString());
}

//Class2
@Transactional
public void createAndSaveSubscribedEms(final String messageName, final String description, final String status) {
    session.save(SubscribedEms.create(messageName, description, status));
}
// Note: No transactional and it was working earlier in hibernate 3 
public void setEMSStatus(String emsName, String newStatus) {
    SubscribedEms subscribedEms = (SubscribedEms) session.createCriteria(SubscribedEms.class).
        add(Restrictions.eq(SubscribedEms_.messageName, emsName)).
        uniqueResult();
    subscribedEms.setStatus(newStatus);
}
```

I came across similar issue
https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/03/migrating-from-hibernate-3-to-4-with-spring-integration.html
But in hibernate 5.1.17 I don't see that class itself.

What changes should I make to get it working?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd"
        >

    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.company.product.da">
        <context:exclude-filter type="regex" expression="com\.company\.product\..*Test\$.*"/>
        <context:exclude-filter type="regex" expression="com\.company\.product\..*TestSupport\$.*"/>
    </context:component-scan>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.company.product.entity.platform.event">
        <context:exclude-filter type="regex" expression="com\.companthis partct\..*Test\$.*"/>
    </context:component-scan>

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="jtaTransactionManager" jndi-name="java:/TransactionManager"/>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" depends-on="jtaTransactionManager"/>

    <import resource="classpath:spring/database-common.xml"/>

    <bean id="eventListenerIntegrator" class="com.company.product.persist.hibernate.EventListenerIntegrator"/>

    <bean id="hibernateSessionFactory" class="com.company.product.persist.hibernate.CustomHibernateSessionFactoryBean"
        depends-on="migrationVersionVerifier">
        <constructor-arg ref = "customInfinispanRegionFactory"/>
        <constructor-arg ref = "eventListenerIntegrator"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties" ref="optionValueStoreProperties" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.company.product.entity" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I enabled logs to see what transaction manager is used.

```
DEBUG [o.s.t.jta.JtaTransactionManager] JTA TransactionManager found at fallback JNDI location [java:/TransactionManager]
INFO  [o.s.t.jta.JtaTransactionManager] Using JTA UserTransaction: org.wildfly.transaction.client.LocalUserTransaction@701458cf
INFO  [o.s.t.jta.JtaTransactionManager] Using JTA TransactionManager: org.wildfly.transaction.client.ContextTransactionManager@2bba8287
DEBUG [o.s.t.jta.JtaTransactionManager] JTA TransactionSynchronizationRegistry found at default JNDI location [java:comp/TransactionSynchronizationRegistry]
INFO  [o.s.t.jta.JtaTransactionManager] Using JTA TransactionSynchronizationRegistry: org.jboss.as.txn.service.internal.tsr.TransactionSynchronizationRegistryWrapper@5437a6d1
```

session.getTransaction().getStatus() is **NOT_ACTIVE**
session.getFlushMode() is **AUTO**
*****Is there any issue with jtaTransactionManager ?? ****

Comment: Can you paste your xml or config Java?

Comment: I have added xml in the main question